# Anafunctors vs the plus construction

Tags: topos-theory, stacks, lie-groupoids, differentiable-stacks

Given a Lie groupoid $G$, we can view it as representing a prestack on $\text{Mfld}$ by sending and manfold $M$ to the groupoid of smooth functors and smooth natural transformations
$$G(M) := \text{Fun}(M,G)$$
(viewing $M$ as a discrete groupoid). One of the multiple ways of improving this prestack to a stack is to instead use anafunctors and ananatural transformations. That is, we localize at coverings so that a manifold $M$ is sent to a groupoid containing objects of the form $M \leftarrow U \rightarrow G $ for coverings $U$ of $M$.

On the other hand, we can apply the plus construction to $G$ to get a stack. This is defined by
$$G^+(M) := \text{colim}_{R \hookrightarrow M}\text{Psh}(R,G).$$
Here the colimit is taken over covering sieves of $M$. This seems to be doing the same thing as the anafunctors are. However, one would not expect to get a stack until the plus construction had been applied 3 times to $G$.

So, my question is: assuming these constructions really are doing the same thing, what about Lie groupoids lets us get away with only applying the plus construction once? Is this a general phenomenon with internal groupoids/geometric stacks, or is ther something special about the underlying site here?

Comment: It's a general phenomenon for internal groupoids in a subcanonical site. For insurance, I guess I should say something like a singleton pretopology + superextensivity.

Comment: I'm not sure it's really saying that you only need to do the plus construction once. Exactly the same thing can be said for sheaves of sets. Also the sense of "localisation" here may be misleading: you need to restrict to reflective localisations. It is [not the free localisation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4705903). All that said, the anafunctor concept has analogues in general categories of fibrant objects, such as Jardine's cocycles and what I call "functional correspondences".

Comment: @DavidRoberts Interesting! Do you have a reference and/or some intution for why this should be the case? My guess would be that such an argument would generalize to say that for internal n-groupoids in a subcanoncial site, one only needs n applications of the plus construction to yield an n-stack rather than the usual n+2. But this seems to not be the case (assuming the analogy between higher anafunctors and the plus construction holds), since anafunctors between Lie n-groupoids are still good enough to get n-stacks.

Comment: Oh, I think I might have cleared up my own confusion on that last point. Does this sound right? Higher anafunctors utilize hypercovers rather than covers, so intuitively that should correspond to doing multiple applications of the plus construction "all at once"

Comment: In the notation $M←U→G$, the middle object is really the Čech nerve of a covering family $U$.  Mapping out of the Čech nerve in particular means mapping out of each simplicial level of the Čech nerve.  The simplicial levels of the Čech nerve correspond to different iterations of the plus construction.  The latter computes the simplicial levels of the sheafification step-by-step as opposed to the single-step Čech nerve construction.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Thanks! That makes a lot of sense

Comment: @Connor one can calculate directly that for a subcanonical unary site $(S,J)$, and a groupoid $X$ internal to $S$, $\mathbf{Gpd}(S)(-,X)$ is a prestack. So only one application of Grothendieck plus construction is needed to make it a stack.

Comment: As for the reason this works, I strongly suspect it's the case that the [Isom presheaves](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02Z9) for $\mathbf{Gpd}(S)(-,X)$ are representable by (the base change of) $X_1$, the object of arrows of $X$. And then by subcanonicity, this representable presheaf is a sheaf hence $\mathbf{Gpd}(S)(-,X)$ is a prestack.

Comment: For the case of a non-unary site, supextensivity reduces the calculation to the unary case, since $\mathbf{Gpd}(S)(-,X)$ is already a stack for the extensive pretopology.

Comment: Regarding the higher stack case, it would be interesting to check what is happening with an internal 2-groupoid and whether it gives rise to a (suitable analogue of a) pre-2-stack, say using the technology in [Breen's book on 2-gerbes and 2-stacks](http://www.numdam.org/issues/AST_1994__225__1_0/).

Comment: @DavidRoberts Your argument sounds good to me. By pre(-2-)stack you're meaning the version that's the analogue of a separated presheaf, rather than a presheaf? If so, it doesn't seem like it'd be the case that you'd get a pre-2-stack from an internal 2-groupoid.

Comment: As @DmitriPavlov said, at that point you'd need higher simplicial degrees in the Czch nerve of a cover to fully capture the 2-stackification, so it seems like it'd be something a little farther away from a 2-stack than a pre-2-stack, right?

Comment: This might be off topic, but it seems like there should be better terminology for all these types of objects that live between "contravariant functors valued in n-groupoids" and "sheaves/stacks"

Comment: @Connor yes, a pre-stack is a presheaf of categories or groupoids such that the comparison functor from the value of the presheaf at an object to every category/groupoid of descent data is fully faithful. It is a stack if this comparison functor is an equivalence. For a presheaf of 2-gpds, there are notions like 1-separated, 2-separated,.... thinking of a 4-ary factorisation system analogous to the one that gives us full, faithful and eso for 1-gpds, and the corresponding notions of separatedness for a presheaf of them.

Comment: I don't know what the correct result is for a preseheaf of 2-groupoids arising from an internal 2-groupoid. That would a good thing to work out from scratch! But I suspect your idea that it might need $n-2$ with $n=4$ applications of the plus construction to get to a stack is the closest to having a chance of being correct, here.

Comment: @ConnorGrady did you want me to type these comments up as an answer?

Comment: @DavidRoberts Yeah! Sorry, I'm not sure about the etiquette on this site yet as far as who writes the answers from comments. But I think it'd be nice to have one typed out answer if it's not too much work for you

Comment: @ConnorGrady technically I'm abusing the comment system, if we believe the overlords at StackExchange, by giving an answer piecemeal like this. I'll write it up for you, as I should do :-)

Comment: @DavidRoberts Much appreciated haha

Comment: @ConnorGrady sorry it's taken me so long! It's on my to-do list.

Comment: @DavidRoberts all good! There's no rush

Comment: @ConnorGrady just a ping to see if you've seen the answer ;-)

Comment: @DavidRoberts Thanks! For some reason I never got a notification when your answer was posted...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>The long-expected answer.</sub> $\DeclareMathOperator{\op}{op} \DeclareMathOperator{\Cat}{\mathbf{Cat}}\DeclareMathOperator{\Gpd}{\mathbf{Gpd}} \DeclareMathOperator{\disc}{disc}\DeclareMathOperator{\pr}{pr}$

Suppose for simplicity, we are in a site $(S,J)$ equipped with a subcanonical singleton pretopology $J$. This means every covering family consists of a single map that is an [effective epimorphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/effective+epimorphism) (the kernel pair exists because of the axioms of a pretopology, and the subcanonicity implies the map is a coequaliser of its kernel pair). For the purposes of your question, the category of smooth manifolds with surjective submersions as covers is such a site. Another way to get such a site is to consider an arbitrary subcanonical and *[superextensive](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/superextensive+site)* pretopology, then form the singleton pretopology consisting of the coproducts of the maps in the covering family. I'll come back to this later.

Recall that the definition of a prestack (for example Vistoli's *[Notes on Grothendieck topologies, fibered categories and descent theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0412512)* Definition 4.6(i)) on an arbitrary site $(S,J)$ is a presheaf $F\colon S^{\op} \to \Cat$ such that for each object $M$ and covering family $\mathcal{U}$ of $M$ the comparison functor
$$
F(M) \to Desc_F(\mathcal{U})
$$
to the category of [descent data](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02ZC) is fully faithful. Let us spell out the definition of $Desc_F(\mathcal{U})$ in the case that we have an internal groupoid $G$, and $F(M) = よ(G)(M) := \Gpd(S)(\disc(M),G)$, for $\disc$ denoting the internal groupoid with no non-identity arrows, and we have a singleton cover $j\colon U\to M$ in the pretopology $J$ as above.

An object of this category (following [Tag 026B](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/026B).(1)) is a internal functor $f_0\colon \disc(U)\to G$ (equivalently, an arbitrary arrow $U\to G_0$ of $S$, for $G_0$ the objects of $G$), equipped with a natural isomorphism
$$
f_1\colon f_0\circ \pr_1 \Rightarrow f_0\circ \pr_2,
$$
where $\pr_i\colon U\times_M U\to U$ projects on the $i^{th}$ coordinate. Such a  natural iso is given by the data of an arrow $f_1\colon U\times_M U \to G_1$ such that $(s\circ f_1,t\circ f_1) = (f_0\circ \pr_1,f_0\circ \pr_2)$. We also require that $f_1$ satisfies as associativity constraint:
$$
\pr_{23}^*f_1 \cdot  \pr_{12}^*f_1 = \pr_{13}^*f_1\colon f_0 \circ\pr_1\Rightarrow f_0\circ \pr_3
$$
between these two functors $\disc(U\times_M U\times_M U) \to G$. Here $\cdot$ denotes the pointwise *internal* composition in $G$. This makes $f_0$ and $f_1$ the data of an internal functor from the Čech groupoid $\check{C}(U\to M)$ of the given cover, to $G$.

However, such a thing is precisely the data of an anafunctor $(U,f)\colon \disc(M)\leftarrow \check{C}(U\to M) \to G$! So we can identify the objects of the descent category with anafunctors, but this is not perhaps as helpful as it seems.

Next, let us calculate what the morphisms $(U,f)\to (U,g)$ are in the category (really, groupoid) of descent data (following [Tag 026B](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/026B).(2)). The data is a natural transformation $a\colon f_0\Rightarrow g_0\colon \disc(U)\to G$ (again, equivalently, a morphism $U\to G_1$ in $S$ etc) satisfying the constraint that
$$
\pr_2^*a \cdot f_1 = g_1\cdot \pr_1^*a\colon f_0\circ\pr_1 \to g_0\circ\pr_2.
$$
This is precisely the definition of internal natural transformation between the two functors $f,g\colon \check{C}(U\to M)\to G$. Now this is *not* the same thing as a transformation between the anafunctors $(U,f)$ and $(U,g)$, the data of which would be a natural transformation $f\circ \pr_1 \Rightarrow g\circ \pr_2\colon \check{C}(U\times_M U\to M) \to \check{C}(U\to M) \to G$.

Composition in this category of descent data agrees with the usual way of composing natural transformations, so that $Desc_{よ(G)}(U\to M) = \Gpd(S)(\check{C}(U\to M),G)$. Moreover, the comparison functor $よ(G)(M) \to Desc_{よ(G)}(U\to M)$ agrees with the precomposition functor $j^*\colon \Gpd(S)(\disc(M),G) \to \Gpd(S)(\check{C}(U\to M),G)$.

So to show that $よ(G)$ is a prestack, we need to consider the action of the functor $j^*$ on hom-sets. Fix then two morphisms $h,k\colon M \to G_0$ of $S$ ($\Leftrightarrow$ functors $\disc(M)\to G$), and a natural transformation
$a\colon h\circ j \Rightarrow k\circ j$. First, note that the arrow component $(h\circ j)_1\colon U\times_M U \to G_1$ is just $e\circ h \circ j'$ for $e\colon G_0\to G_1$ the unit map, and $j'\colon U\times_M U\to M$ the projection. Similarly, $(k\circ j)_1 = e\circ k \circ j'$.

The natural transformation is $a$ is given by the data of a function (abusing notation slightly) $a\colon U\to G_1$ such that $\pr_2^*a \cdot (h\circ j)_1 = (k\circ j)_1\cdot \pr_1^*a$. Recall that here $\circ$ is composition of arrows in $S$, and $\cdot$ is pointwise composition of internal morphisms in $G$. Keeping this in mind, and using the calculation earlier, this gives
$$
\pr_2^*a \cdot (e\circ h \circ j') = (e\circ k \circ j')\cdot \pr_1^*a
$$
as natural transformations between functors $\check{C}(U\times_M U)\to G$. But this amounts to saying two particular arrows $U\times_M U \to G_1$ are equal. What are these arrows?
Unwinding the above equation, each side is the internal composition of the component of a natural transformation with an identity arrow (because of the unit map $e$). But we need to calculate this in a slightly easier way.

We are now going to reason using generalised elements to check the two arrows $U\times_M U \to G_1$ are in fact equal.
Suppose that $(u_1,u_2)$ is a generalised element of $U\times_M U$, satisfying $j(u_1) = j(u_2) =:m$. Then $\pr_2^*a(u_1,u_2) = a(u_2)$ and $\pr_1^*a(u_1,u_2) = a(u_1)$, generalised elements of $G_1$. Now $a(u_2) \colon h(j(u_2)) \to k(j(u_2))$, which is just $a(u_2) = h(m) \to k(m)$ and likewise $a(u_1) \colon h(m)=h(j(u_1)) \to k(j(u_1)) = k(m)$, as arrows in $G$. So $a(u_1)$ and $a(u_2)$ are parallel arrows. Then the condition they need to satisfy is nothing other than $a(u_2)\cdot e_{h(m)} = e_{k(m)}\cdot a(u_1)$, which is to say that $a(u_2) = a(u_1)$. This is true for arbitrary generalised elements, so by Yoneda we have $a\circ \pr_2 = a\circ\pr_1$, so that $a\colon U\to G_1$ coequalises the parallel pair $\pr_1,\pr_2\colon U\times_M U\rightrightarrows U$. But since $j$ is the coequaliser of this parallel pair, by subcanonicity of $J$, we have a *unique* $a'\colon M\to G_1$ such that $a = j^*a'$.

Thus $j^*$ is fully faithful, and hence $よ(G)$ is a prestack.

Now, what if we don't want to use the singleton pretopology, but a general subcanonical superextensive pretopology? For instance, consider the case of the site of manifolds with open covers for covering families, or more generally, collections of submersions that are jointly-surjective. This is very close to, but not identical with, the site with only singleton covering families. In particular, one needs to consider the covering families given by coproduct injections, and of course everything generated from the combination of the two types of covering families. But, and this is the good point, an internal functor $\check{C}(\coprod_{i\in I}U_i\to M)\to G$ (given the extensivity of the ambient category $S$) is still equivalent to an object of the category of descent data! This is because a map $\coprod_{i\in I}U_i \to G_0$ is equivalent to a collection of maps $\{U_i \to G_0\}_{i\in I}$, and the definition of the descent category's objects in the non-singleton case amounts to defining a functor as above, and vice-versa. Similarly, the data of the natural transformation giving a morphism of descent data in the singleton case is equivalent to what it should be in the non-singleton case. The rest of the calculation goes through as before. One might also consider $\kappa$-extensivity for any given arity class $\kappa$ (eg finite extensivity, small extensivity, or even the degenerate case where we only consider "1-extensivity", which amounts to the original singleton case), and this all works fine.

So, to sum up: for an arbitrary subcanonical superextensive site $(S,J)$, the presheaf $よ(G)$ is a prestack for *any* internal groupoid $G$ in $S$ (so, for instance, one might wish to put some constraints of the source and target maps of $G$, but this is irrelevant to the above calculation). Note in particular that I haven't assumed $S$ has finite limits.

After this, one might want to consider the non-superextensive case. I believe that careful book-keeping should allow the above to go through, keeping track of the various components. In the end, one will use that the representable presheaf associated to the object $G_1$ of $S$ is actually a sheaf, and the last calculation given checks that one has descent data for that sheaf. So I'm willing to claim one only needs $(S,J)$ subcanonical for this to work, and that the data of a topology is fine to use, rather than a pretopology. And, further, that really one only needs to know that the presheaf $よ(G_1)$ (of sets) is a sheaf for the (pre)topology to get that the presheaf $よ(G)$ (of groupoids) is a prestack.

The only other generalisation I haven't touched on is when $G$ is instead an internal *category* that's not a groupoid. I believe this case should work too, since there was nothing in the above that actually *used* the fact $G$ was a groupoid. The category of descent data is then a category that's not a groupoid, but that doesn't affect anything, and I think the proof actually goes through unchanged. So, barring some tedious checking of book-keeping, I think I can claim:

**Theorem:** Given a site $(S,J)$ and an internal category $C$ in $S$ such that the representable presheaf on $S$ associated to the object of arrows $C_1$ is a $J$-sheaf, the presheaf $よ(C)$ of categories is a prestack.

Now, to go back to the original question, this means that one only needs to apply the Grothendieck $+$-construction *once* to $よ(C)$ in order to get a stack on $(S,J)$.

Moreover, at least under the assumption that $(S,J)$ is subcanonical, and $J$ is singleton (or at the very least, superextensive), the [bicategory of internal anafunctors construction](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/26/29/26-29abs.html) gives a localisation of the 2-category $\Cat(S)$ (and analogously for the full sub-2-category $\Gpd(S)$) at the internal functors $\check{C}(U\to M) \to \disc(M)$ (using the more general version in *[The elementary construction of formal anafunctors](https://doi.org/10.52547/cgasa.15.1.183)*, using Example 2.11). <s>And we also have that the 2-category of stacks is *also* a localisation (from Pronk and Warren, *[Bicategorical fibration structures and stacks](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/29/29/29-29abs.html)*), and so the anafunctor bicategory and the 2-category of stacks are **equivalent** (here recalling we are in a subcanonical site, which Pronk and Warren assume). As a result objects of the the anafunctor bicategory essentially arise from performing the Grothendieck $+$-construction just once.</s>

**EDIT** I need to correct that last statement. What is true is that the bicategory of internal categories, anafunctors and transformations is a localisation of the 2-category of internal categories, functors and transformations, and so is the 2-category of *presentable* stacks. Pronk and Warren's result is about localising the 2-category of prestacks (which the representable ones of the form $よ(G)$ form a full sub-2-category) at the local equivalences to get the 2-category of stacks. The local equivalences in the case of representable prestacks amount to (IIRC) the internal weak equivalences as in my work. The essential image of the 2-category of representable prestacks in the 2-category of all stacks under the localisation 2-functor of Pronk and Warren should be the 2-category of presentable stacks (I say should be, because I think I once checked this, and have promised to publish this result for a long time!). So you can combine all these ingredients to get that the 2-category of presentable stacks is equivalent to the anafunctor bicategory. It's a story I really need to write up properly one day, and it is to my shame that it hasn't happened yet...

Comment: Wow, thanks for writing this all up! This definitely clears up the whole story in my mind :)

Comment: Now to see if I can just follow your same steps to prove the same things for higher internal groupoids and higher stacks or if there are obstructions at some point (besides my own brain power haha)

Comment: @ConnnorGrady drop me an email if you want to discuss :-)